# Batch File to check if list of files exist. Doesn't work with spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I have a list of files in a text file and I would like to generate a report of any files that do not exist. I tried creating a batch file with the following code however it does not work with any files that have a space in it's path:

```
FOR /F %%f IN (filelist.txt) DO (IF EXIST %%f (ECHO %%f exists) ELSE (ECHO %%f doesn't exist >> C:\doesntexist.txt ))
```

In my output file I get an error like "C:\Documents doesn't exist" showing that it didnt parse the full file name.

How can I fix this so that I can check all files even with spaces in it's path?

Answer (score 7):

Wherever there is a possibility that a string may contain a separator like a space, you need to `"enclose that string in quotes"`

`for /f` **tokenises** the data it receives by default on separators, so the first nominated token is assigned to the metavariable (`%%f` in your case), the next to `%%g` and so on.

You can control how many tokens and the delimiter(s) and other parsing characteristics by using command-modifiers (from the prompt, see `for /?`)

In your case, you want just the one token with no delimiters (the default is 1 token and delimiters=*separators*) so

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN (filelist.txt) DO (IF EXIST "%%f" (ECHO %%f exists) ELSE (ECHO %%f doesn't exist >> C:\doesntexist.txt ))
```

There is a small extra complication if `filelist.txt` contains spaces. In that case, you'd need

```
FOR /F "usebackqdelims=" %%f IN ("filelist.txt") DO (IF EXIST "%%f" (ECHO %%f exists) ELSE (ECHO %%f doesn't exist >> C:\doesntexist.txt ))
```

for reasons that ate "explained" in the documentation `for /?` referred to above.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That worked and it kind of makes sense too :D

Answer (score 1):

You must use quotes:

```
FOR /F %%f IN (filelist.txt) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%f" (ECHO "%%f" exists) ELSE (ECHO %%f doesn't exist >> C:\doesntexist.txt )
)
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: You're right, I missed `"delims="` to also consider reading full lines from file!